# LISP - Make new unique symbol

Tags: common-lisp, symbols

In a Common Lisp program, I want to find a way to generate a new symbol that is not in use in the program at the time. I am aware of the (gensym) function, but this makes symbols that may already be present in the program. I have some understanding that I need to intern the symbol, so I tried this:

```
(defun new-symbol () (intern (symbol-name (gensym))))
```

Which seems to get halfway to the answer. For instance,

```
[1]> (new-symbol)
G3069
NIL
[2]> (new-symbol)
G3070
NIL
[3]> (defvar a 'G3071)
A
[4]> (new-symbol)
G3071
:INTERNAL
```

As you can see, the function seems to recognize that the symbol 'G3071' is already in use elsewhere, but I don't know how to get it to generate a new symbol if that is the case.

Answer (score 8):

> *I am aware of the (gensym) function, but this makes symbols that may already be present in the program.*

No, it doesn't.  It creates symbols that aren't interned in any package. The documentation says (emphasis added):

> #### [Function GENSYM](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_gensym.htm)
>
> **Syntax:**
>
> gensym &optional x ⇒ new-symbol
>
> **Arguments and Values:**
>
> x—a string or a non-negative integer. Complicated defaulting
>   behavior; see below.
>
> new-symbol—**a fresh, uninterned symbol.**

You can also use [**make-symbol**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_sym.htm#make-symbol) to create a symbol that's not interned in any package.  It's documentation summary (pretty much identical to **gensym**'s):

> #### [Function MAKE-SYMBOL](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_sym.htm#make-symbol)
>
> **Syntax:**
>
> make-symbol name ⇒ new-symbol
>
> **Arguments and Values:**
>
> name—a string.
>
> new-symbol—**a fresh, uninterned symbol.**

Regarding your second point:

> *I have some understanding that I need to intern the symbol, so I tried this:*

No, if you want a fresh symbol, then you probably *don't* want to be interning anywhere.  Interning is the process whereby you take a *string* (not a symbol) and get the symbol with the given name within a particular package.  If you call **intern** with the same symbol name and package twice, you'll get back *the same symbol*, which is what you're trying to avoid.

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *a* (intern "A"))
*A*
CL-USER> (eq *a* (intern "A"))
T
```

Since **gensym** generates the name of the fresh symbol using ***gensym-counter***, if you take the name from the **gensym** symbol and intern it somewhere, you could get the same symbol if someone modifies the value of ***gensym-counter***.  E.g.:

```
(let ((counter *gensym-counter*)    ; save counter value
      (s1 (gensym)))                ; create a gensym (s1)
  (setf *gensym-counter* counter)   ; reset counter value
  (let ((s2 (gensym)))              ; create a gensym (s2)
    (list s1                        
          s2            
          (eq s1 s2)
          (symbol-name s1) 
          (symbol-name s2)
          (string= (symbol-name s1)
                   (symbol-name s2)))))

; (#:G1037 #:G1037 NIL      ; different symbols
;  "G1037" "G1037" T)       ; same name
```